# Model structure : Data Mapper vs Orm for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, rad

I'm used to create my business logic inside my dbtable classes, but from what I read, it's a bad design.

I've been reading a lot of articles about Model Architecture for zend framework but I'm still confused of what approach I should  use.

Based from your experience, what approach do you use? (Datamappers or by using ORM) *(also taking into consideration Rapid Application Development)*

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question. Asking a `Which one is better` will get you votes to close every time.

Comment: @RockyFord Yup, you were right :)

Answer (score 2):

To try and provide a little help,

The reason that using the ZF DbTable classes to hold your business logic is that doing so violates "separation of concerns".

By doing something like:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Genre extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'genre';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

    public function fetchAllGenre()
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->order('name ASC');

        $result = $this->fetchAll($select);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Your model becomes coupled to your database. So if you have to change data sources you will have to refactor every piece of code that touches this table.

Now you can and should use the DbTable models that ZF provides, but use them in concert with a data mapper and a domain model.

```
//Domain Model
class Video_Model_Genre extends Jgs_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    protected $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

//The mapper
class Video_Model_Mapper_Genre extends Jgs_Model_Mapper_Abstract
{
    protected $_tableName = 'genre';

    function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway = null)
    {
        //Pass in the DbTable Model, This is the database adapter for this mapper.
        $tableGateway = new Application_Model_DbTable_Genre();
        parent::__construct($tableGateway);
    }

   //create the domain object 
    protected function createEntity($row)
    {
        $data = array(
            'id'   => $row->id,
            'name' => $row->name
        );

        return new Video_Model_Genre($data);
    }

    public function saveGenre(Video_Model_Genre $genre)
    {

        if (!is_null($genre->id)) {
            $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
            $select->where('id = ?', $genre->id);
            $row = $this->getGateway()->fetchRow($select);
        } else {
            $row = $this->getGateway()->createRow();
        }
        $row->name = $genre->name;

        $row->save();
        return $row;
    }
}
```

[Note:] If you want to see the base/abstract classes used to build these classes, [Github, Library](https://github.com/jschoenwolf/home-local.git)

The thing that is really important about using mappers and domain models is that the domain 
model doesn't care where the data comes from. If you have multiple sources of data you can build a mapper to each data source that builds the same Domain model.

For instance, if I had an XML file that had all of the information required to build 'genre' objects, I could build a mapper that used that XML file as the data source, but I would still use the same domain model to build the 'genre' objects.

As far as using an ORM. ORM's can be great, after you know how to use it. The learning curve for most ORM's is pretty steep. Let's face it, if you don't yet know and understand how to implement a data mapper pattern, your probably not ready for an ORM. I know I'm not (it's taken me 3 months to get this far with mappers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RockyFord, I also want to see an answer based from a doctrine user. Btw, how does a datamapper handle table relationships?

Comment: http://phpmaster.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/ covers this at length.